# HTML, JavaScript: Frameless Windows

Tags: javascript, html, web

How to produce **frameless window** in HTML5, JavaScript, please?

I searched the web and found mostly links to use libraries. I wish to develop my own frameless window from scratch, without using a third party library.

By frameless window I mean a window having no frames, no status bar, no default minimize button, no default close button, no roll bars... It looks like a standalone image with painted close button.

Would be anybody so kind and provide me with ideas or code that will be accepted by most of the browsers?

### EXAMPLE:

As few of you asked, what exactly I mean, I found a very nice **example** at [Rapidshare](https://rapidshare.com/). There is a large **blue/orange button** in the middle of the screen saying **Upload**. Just press it, please, and a frameless window appears.

The window represents exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have seen it many times, when displaying enlarged images, or prompting for login information, etc.. I like the animation associated with displaying that window too.

Comment: If you can give more information about where and why you want to do it, we might be able to suggest you alternative solutions. It is anyway not directly possible in all browsers through JavaScript. You can simply also let the user run your website in fullscreen (common key F11) (or commandline; Opera has even a Kiosk mode!).

Comment: @Styxxy: Hi. thanks for your comment. I added example into the problem/question description area.

Comment: That's just some kind of "lightbox". Look on the interwebz, there are plenty of good scripts to achieve this.

Comment: @Styxxy: would you provide url to interwebz, please? I quickly tried interwebz.com and searched through Google, but seemingly, i did not find the right link.

Comment: By using the keywords "lightbox" + "html" I think you come very far: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=lightbox+html&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 . Obviously you have to do some work yourself as in including and wiring the actual thing, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Styxxy, +1 - indeed "lightbox" is the keyword I needed to discover. There are many links on Google. Thank Styxxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for quicks to show the concept ..

create two divs directly under body

```
  <div id="backmask"></div>
  <div id="contentwindow"></div>

  <!-- somewhere else in your page -->
  <a href="somepage.html" class="showinwindow">click me</a>
```

css for these ( roughly )

```
  <style type="text/css">

    #backmask { 
      display:block; 
      width:100%;
      height:100%;  
      background-color:black;
      position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
      z-index:1000;
      display:none;

      opacity:0.7;
      filter:alpha(opacity=70);
     }

    #contentwindow { 
      display:block; 
      width:800px;
      height:600px;  
      background-color:white;
      position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px;
      z-index:1001;
      display:none;
     }

    .bodywithwinOpenClass { overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:100%; }
  </style>
```

and then ( im using jquery for quicks )

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(".showinwindow").click( function(e) {

   /* we don't want the visitor to leave, stop the normal action */
   e.preventDefault();

   /* get what to show */
    var contenttoload = $(this).attr.("href");

  /* set the body up */
  $("body").addClass("bodywithwinOpenClass");

   /* show wins and masker */
   $("#backmask").css("display","block");
   $("#contentwindow").css("display","block");

  /* load the content  */
  $("#contentwindow").load(contenttoload);

   });
   </script>
```

this was just typed in directly and not ran, contains no candy ( for positioning etc ) hope it explains the concept behind all the pluggins etc you will find

- the reverse is needed to "close" it

Comment: +1, Hi Rob and thanks for your detailed explanation. It clearly shows, that what I mean are just two divs, and the idea with backmask is very good. Thank you for making so much effort and writing so much code for me.

Comment: Despite more developers provided good answers, I think, Rob provided the most detailed information, and put most effort into his answer. Therefore, I wish to mark this answer as the *Accepted Answer* to my question. Thank you all, for all your great comments.

Answer (score 1):

> no frames

That's your decision to use (i)frames in your document or not

> no scroll bars

With CSS you can suppress scroll bars, or build a layout which resizes exactly to the window size

> no status bar, no minimize, no close, no roll bars...

That is possible with chrome-feature descriptors when creating a popup with [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). Yet, you will not be able to create unclosable windows, hiding the close buttons also [requires some privileges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#Features_requiring_privileges).

You seem to want a fullscreen application. Have you considered using the new [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode)?

Comment: +1, hi Bergi. Thank you for your answer. Great ideas. Well, basically, I am looking for something like [this](https://rapidshare.com/). If you click on the large orange **Upload** button, a new window appears in the middle of the screen. It has nice animated effect associated with it, and it looks very nice to me. Is it possible to achieve it with the iFrames, as you say?

Comment: Oh, that's just a simple animated <div> element at a fixed position, no window. I thought you'd asked for a browser window...

Comment: Yeah, sorry Bergi, I did not know that. Now I do know. Thank you for your great advice, ane Fulscreen API looks very interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/amazingframelesspopup1.html <-- pretty much covers all you can do - you can't launch a chromeless browser window from a web page.

What are you trying to achieve?

That's easy enough - it's not a window - it's actually a div on the page floating over the rest of the page content - there are plenty of ways to do it with a framework like jQuery.

[Tutorial](http://www.webstutorial.com/jquery-popup-jquery-slide-popup/jquery)

Essentially all you need is a **hidden** positioned div with a high **z-index** and a bit of script to show/hide it:

```
<div id="popup" style="z-index:1000;display:none;position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;">Some content</div>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';">Open</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';">Close</button>
```

Comment: +1 for good tip. Hi, web_bod, I have seen the link even before. However, it works only with IE, as the source says. To answer the question, what I am trying to achieve, as an example, please go to: [Rapidshare](https://rapidshare.com/) and click on the large orange **Upload** buton. I wish to know, **how to create such a frameless window** that gets opened after pressing that Upload button.

Comment: *"I wish to develop my own frameless window from scratch, without using a third party library."*

Comment: @web_bod: this is new information, that it is just a floating div on the webpage. :-) I think, it should be possible to easily remove the jQuery, right?

Comment: yes - the idea of the link was to show you what was going on - piece of cake to implement in css/javascript - but you miss out on the animations (swings and roundabouts)

Comment: Yeah, but i should be able to create the animations on my own, using `setInterval()` - timer. Is it really so great to implement jQuery? i will study more about this library.